# How to edit swf file?

Tags: flash-cs5

I have a flash template. It is linked to a .swf file. I am new to flash i dont know anything about it.  Can someone please tell me how to edit a .swf file. I want to change some text which is written in it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit a SWF file. You can only edit a FLA file which SWF files are compiled from. But there are some reverse engineering tools that converts SWF files to FLA's such as: SWF Decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with flash is limited but in my experience you either need to decompile a .swf or have access to the original .fla to be able to change the contents of a .swf-file.